# Is this question really "subjective"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wrote the following question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407591/is-simple-directmedia-layer-at-a-lower-level-than-a-library-like-qt-or-is-it

Before it was put on hold, I received an answer that meshed with the little I knew, so I was inclined to believe it. I let someone know, who initially commented that the question was not good, that I thought it was answerable (it isn't primarily opinion based...it basically needs a simple pros and cons analysis from someone who knows both tools), and that I had received a good answer.

They retorted back by saying that the answer is a bit wrong, and made fun of the ability of the answerer to write. Now, I don't understand: if the question's answers are easy to judge in terms of correctness, doesn't that stand as greater proof that the question is *not* primarily opinion based?

Comment: Regarding that comment you mention that was made about the answer you got, if you find the comment to be rude you can flag it as such. (This has no bearing on whether your question should be closed or not but I thought you should know.)

Answer (score 12):

The question isn't closed for being subjective (but the answer that you feel is so good opening with "Here is my opinion" is certainly a red flag that it probably is); it's closed for being too broad, which it most certainly is.

You're asking **five** different questions (that alone is a pretty big red flag that your post is too broad) and of them, some are reasonably objective, some are partly subjective, and some are very subjective.  There's certainly merit in closing the question for being too subjective, but there's really no question at all that it's too broad.  Most of the individual questions that you're asking are individually too broad, and you're asking **5** of them.

Comment: I do not understand why it would be too broad. It doesn't ask one to compare SDL and Qt over *all* possible use cases, but instead it asks specifically about *when* SDL might be preferred over Qt, and *how* SDL differs from Qt.How is that broad?

Comment: @user89 How is comparing *all* of the differences between two libraries *not* too broad?  Do you honestly think you can provide a comprehensive list of every single difference in just a few paragraphs of content?  And that's not even *starting* to bring up each of the other questions you're asking.